# How can i store data from Excel to Database in ThinkPHP

Tags: php, mysql, excel, thinkphp

I wish to store my data from Excel to Database. I am new to ThinkPHP, so i am struggling with more than 3 days.

Upload is working but The data not updated into database. Error not shown in Page also. I dont know , the coding is correct or wrong. 
**Html Coding**

```
    <form name="importForm" id="importForm" action="__APP__" method="POST"> 
    <input type="file" name="file" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="import_csv_payment();"  value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

**Script**

```
function import_csv_payment()
{
    var query = $("#importForm").serialize();
    var url= ROOT+"?"+VAR_MODULE+"="+MODULE_NAME+"&"+VAR_ACTION+"=import_csv_payment"+"&"+query;
    location.href = url;
}
```

**Php Modules**

This is my upload and storing Function

```
public function import_csv_payment($page = 1)
{
if (!empty($_FILES)) 
{
  import("@.ORG.UploadFile");
  $config=array(
      'allowExts'=>array('xlsx','xls'),
      'savePath'=>'./Public/upload/',
      'saveRule'=>'time',
  );

  $upload = new UploadFile($config);
  if (!$upload->upload()) {
     $this->error($upload->getErrorMsg());
  } else {
     $info = $upload->getUploadFileInfo();
  }
  vendor("PHPExcel.PHPExcel");
  $file_name=$info[0]['savepath'].$info[0]['savename'];

  $handle = fopen($file_name, “r”);
  $c = 0;
  while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, “,”)) !== false)
  {
        $id = $filesop[0];
        $deal_name = $filesop[1];
        $ngo = $filesop[2];
        $project = $filesop[3];

        $update = $GLOBALS['db']->query("update ".DB_PREFIX."payment_notice set deal_name = '".$deal_name."',ngo='".$ngo."',project='".$project."' where id = '".$id."' "); 

   $c++;
  }
    $this->success('Import success！');
  } else  {
    $this->error("Please choose to upload the file");
  }     
}
```